# How to disable cache for all methods of a given RestController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 2 controllers, `WebControllerA` and `RestControllerB`. I want to disable cache for all methods of `RestControllerB`, and for this controller only.

I have tried this:

```
@RestController
public class RestControllerB {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noStore());
    }

    ...
}
```

This is working, but it apparently affects both `WebControllerA` and `RestControllerB`, probably because `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` is shared with both of them.

I'm looking for the most simple solution for this problem, with minimal extra classes, and it doesn't have to use `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` at all. However, I'm also looking for a class-level solution, setting a cache-control at method level is not an option.

I'm using spring-boot with no xml.

Edit: Unfortunately both controllers are using the same URL path base, so it is not possible to filter the response by path only.

Comment: Use the `WebContextInterceptor` and register it for a specific path.

Comment: I assume you mean `WebContentInterceptor`... How I do that - should I create a new configuration class? (I'm new to Spring)

Comment: Why would you need to create a new configuration class. You already have one that has `@EnableWebMvc` on it (assuming you are using javacofig). Just let it extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and override the `addInterceptors` method and configure yours accordingly.

Comment: Well, I use `SpringBootServletInitializer` but I see your point. I defined `@Bean public WebMvcConfigurer createWebMvcConfigurer() {...}` instead. Although this solution is applied globally (to both controllers), I can still use it. Thanks!

Comment: You can specify a filter path and only target the URL's/requests that one controller receives.